# Record program and mic on two separate tracks with ffmpeg

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, jack

For my radio show/podcast I'm recording my microphone and play music from a music player software. So far I've used audacity and it records both inputs into one track. This is hard for post-production when I want to edit my microphone input separately from the music. So, what would be ideal is to record the mic and the audio on two separate tracks. I already have two virtual sinks via PulseAudio for that and wonder if I can simply route them into ardour.

I have the feeling that ardour can only deal with hardware devices, so another option would be to output the virtual sink on a hardware device and plugin that back into a hardware input. However, this would lead to quality loss which would be unfortunate.

Edit: Found a solution with ffmpeg (see answer).

Comment: Why just don't you open a 2nd track on Audacity, which would be composed just with music? Also, this question would be more suitable for [Sound Design](https://sound.stackexchange.com/) or [Amateur Radio](https://ham.stackexchange.com/), since it's more about music than Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Today I accidentely stumbled across [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZs7KqEnm30). It doesn't show how to do it in Ardour. However, it shows how you can record several sources at the same time from pulseaudio (including my created virtual sinks).

Quick summary:

1. Find your input sources with `pacmd list-source-outputs | grep source:`
   [image: output]
2. Use ffmpeg

This doesn't guarantee sync though!
`ffmpeg -f pulse -i [Your input source 1] -map '0' 0.mp3 -f pulse -i [Your input source 2] -map '1' 1.mp3`

Comment: Do you find a delay between the two sources in the output files? Eg, 0.mp3 might be half a second or more behind 1.mp3?